# How to Hide JDialog in Windows 10 Task View

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, jdialog

I'm developing a simple software app that uses a `JDialog` as a semi-transparent wall as windows 10 Lock screen. But When it appears someone using the `windows 10` can close the `jDialog` by pressing the Task View icon (Near cortana icon) and close it. So the whole point of giving the security wall is just a myth and vanished. I need to hide my `jDialog` in **windows 10 Task View**. Can someone please tell me how Can I achieve that? Can anyone please give me an idea???

This is the `jDialog` looks like when I start the application
[image: [Screenshot 1]

This is when I press the **Task View in Windows 10**[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Not sure you can, you could consider looking into Kiosk mode :/

Comment: I didn't get you... Can you specify :(

Comment: It is not working :/ I have set the Fullscreen mode and Always on top functions... but the problem is the **Task View**

Comment: Google "Windows Kiosk Mode" - it's the only way you can control the task manager - but I doubt it will provide you with the solution you are seeking

Comment: Then it is useless :/ :(

Comment: AFIK you can't disable the task switcher outside of using kiosk mode - it's kind of a security measure

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you gain special privileges from Windows

Comment: Then there is no solution at all :(